# Arduino Encoder Rotatorio LPD3806 - 600BM

Tags: c#, c, arduino, rotação

Tenho um projeto para a faculdade em que tenho que realizar uma roda medidora. No caso usei um encoder rotatorio para realizar as medidas, mas estou tendo problemas na hora do codigo. No caso, no momento não sei programar um encoder rotativo, estou fazendo uma pesquisa para achar mais informaçoões. O codigo que tenho é:

```
volatile unsigned int temp, counter = 0;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING); 
    attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);
}

void loop() 
{
    if (counter != temp) 
    { 
        Serial.println(counter);
        temp = counter; 
    }
}

void ai0() 
{ 
    if (digitalRead(3) == LOW)
        counter++;
    else 
        counter--;
}

void ai1() 
{
    if (digitalRead(2) == LOW) 
        counter--;
    else 
        counter++;
}
```

PROBLEMA: No codigo quando eu giro a roda para o contador diminuir (-1) e ele esta na posição 0 ele acaba pulando para +65874 no valor positivo, precisaria que, quando ele estivesse na posição 0 e rodasse para diminuir (-1) ele não sairia do 0, Pois a roda não contará um valor negativo. No projeto estou usando um LCD para as posições.

Comment: Não bastaria, então, antes de decrementar o valor, verificar se ele é zero?

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui dentro do codigo mas mesmo assim ele ainda continua pulando para +8345. Quando ele esta em 0 e o comando do encoder e de subtrair ele pula para +8345.

Comment: Você tem de colocar a condição tanto na função ai0(), quanto na função ai1(). Veja o exemplo para a função ai0() na minha resposta.

Comment: Coloquei ela em ambas, mas dai quando vou ver no Serial, ele nao sai de 0 mesmo girando o encoder.                                                                                     

void ai0() { 
    if(digitalRead(3)==LOW){ 
        contador++;
    }else if (contador != 0){
        contador--;
    }
}
   
void ai1() {
 
    if(digitalRead(2)==LOW){ 
        contador++;
    }else if (contador != 0){
        contador--;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Antes de realizar um decremento `couter--`, faça uma verificação se o `counter` é diferente de zero. Por exemplo:

```
void ai0() 
{ 
    if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) 
        counter++;
    else if (counter != 0)
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Usei "else if(counter != 0)" para evidenciar a resposta, mas "else if (counter)" tem o mesmo efeito.